# Undefined variable in dompdf for fonts?

Tags: dompdf

In my log file I am getting this :

```
Undefined variable: rootDir in /lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php on line 69
```

On dozens of lines.  This only happened after I updated to newest dompdf version.  Is there something I missed?

Comment: Specifically which version are you using? `$rootDir` should be defined in the FontMetrics method prior to consuming that file.

Comment: @BrianS Version cee6a79

Comment: That was very specific! I don't see any particular reason this would happen. Is there more to the error message? You might try downloading a fresh copy, I have seen instances where the source was mangled during download/extract.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in top of the problematic file `dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php`:

```
$rootDir = dirname(/__FILE__/);
```